# Can't find the connection between 2 probabilities

Tags: probability

Probability $A$ is $\frac{4}{5}$ times bigger than probability $B$. Does that mean $4P(A)=5P(B)$ or am I understanding something wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means $P(A) = (1 + \frac{4}{5})\times P(B)$. Multiply both sides by five and you get $5P(A) = 9P(B)$.

Comment: So, if someone says "$x$ is $7$ times bigger than $y$", they mean $x=8y$? Not clear to me.

Comment: @MiceElf, yeah, that would be consistent with the usual interpretation.

Comment: @kviiri I guess you meant $\left(1+{4\over 5}\right)$?

Comment: @Karlo Thanks, this is indeed a better notation for mixed fractions.